# react native socket response not updating in view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have connect socket successfully and getting proper response also from socket connection. State is updating successfully but issue is data is not updating in screen (renderTabSection not render updated data).

```
class Test extends Component{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const { restaurantId } = this.props;
        this.socket = new WebSocket('wss://test.com/' + id);
        this.socket.onopen = (data) =>{
            console.log('Socket connected');
        }
        this.socket.onmessage = (e) => {
            this.props.socketData(e.data);
            //this.socketUpdate();
        };
        this.socket.onclose = () => {
            this.socket = new WebSocket('wss://test.com/' + id);
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.resetVenueDetails();
        this.props.showLoader();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.renderTabSection();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.socket.close();
    }

    onTabClick(tabId){
        this.props.onTabChange(tabId);
    }

    renderTabSection(){
        let playlist = this.props.playlists;
        const { 
            container, 
            tabHeaderStyle, 
            tabHeadStyle, 
            tabDetailBox, 
            albumTextStyle, 
            selectedTabStyle,
            hideTabContentStyle
        } = styles;
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, borderBottomColor: '#000', borderBottomWidth: 2 }}>
                <View style={{flex:0,flexDirection:'row'}}>
                    <View style={tabHeadStyle}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onTabClick.bind(this,1)}>
                            <Text style={ [tabHeaderStyle, this.props.tabSelected == 1 ? selectedTabStyle : '' ] }>
                                Playlist
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={[container, this.props.tabSelected == 1 ? "" : hideTabContentStyle]} >
                    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: 'row' }}>  
                            { this.renderPlaylistAlbums('user', playlist) }
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderPlaylistAlbums(type, playlist){
        let songsArray = [];

        const {  tabDetailBox, albumTextStyle } = styles;

        playlist = playlist.length > 0 ? playlist : PLAYLIST_SECTION;
        playlist.filter( (data, i) => {
            if( data.type == type ){
                if(data.songs.length > 0 ){
                    let image = data.songs[0] && data.songs[data.songs.length -1].imageUrl ?
                                { uri : data.songs[data.songs.length -1].imageUrl } : 
                                require('../assets/images/playlist.png'); 

                    let imageStyle = data.songs[0] && data.songs[data.songs.length -1].imageUrl ?
                                        { width: '70%',height:'60%', borderRadius: 10 } : 
                                        { width: '60%',height:'60%' };
                    songsArray.push(
                        <TouchableOpacity key={i}>
                            <View style={ tabDetailBox }>
                                <Image 
                                    source={ image } 
                                    style={ imageStyle } />
                                <Text style={ albumTextStyle }>{ data.name }</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }
            }
        });
        return songsArray;
    }

    loadSpinner(){
        if( this.props.loading ){
            return ( <View style={{ flex:1, position:'absolute', width:'100%' }} ><Spinner /></View> );
        } 
    }
    render(){
        const { backgroundImage } = styles;
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ImageBackground source={APP_BACKGROUND_IMAGE.source} style={backgroundImage}>
                    { this.loadSpinner() }
                    <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.7)' }}>
                        { this.renderTabSection() }
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
                <Footer headerText='Home' />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        error:state.home.error,
        loading:state.home.loading,
        tabSelected:state.restaurantDetail.tabSelected,
        playlists: state.restaurantDetail.playlists
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { onTabChange, socketData, showLoader, resetVenueDetails })(Test)
```

I have connect socket successfully and getting proper response also from socket connection. State is updating successfully but issue is data is not updating in screen (renderTabSection not render updated data).

Comment: Are you sure your redux store is being updated when you dispatch the action with the data received from socket?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting any state because setState will cause the component to re-render, this is how you can setState

```
constructor(props){
   this.state = {
    dataUpdated: false,
    anyUseFullVariable: '',
   }
}
```

you can setState when you get response from sockets like this

```
this.setState({dataUpdated: true})
```

then you can use the state within render component like this

```
this.state.dataUpdated
```

this will re-render the component. This is just an example try doing something similar.

**Update**

You can also use componentWillRecieveProps, this callback function is triggered whenever there is some change in props

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  if(!isFetching && this.props.data !== nextProps.data) // or implement your preferred condition
    this.setState({UpdateList: this.props.data}) // this would call the render function
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: yes i tried this. This is working but i wants to implement using redux.

Comment: Then you need to dispatch an Action and need to make reducers, did you look at redux implementation or have implemented it before?